# surpress output of get-azureaddomain

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

using below snippet :

```
#loop until we have found the newly added domain
$Stop='' 
while (-not $Stop) 
{
    $stop = Get-AzureADDomain -Name $direct_routing_domain -ErrorAction Ignore | Out-Null
    if (!$stop)
    {
        Write-Host "Domain is not provisioned yet - retrying in 60 seconds..." -ForegroundColor Yellow 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
}
Write-Host "Domain is provisioned " -ForegroundColor Green
```

**The output gives an error on stdout:**

Get-AzureADDomain : Error occurred while executing GetDomain
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
...

**So here comes the question: how can I surpress this output ?   I believe that | out-null should be enough. Or is this a bug in AzureAd 2.0.0 module ?**

Answer (score 0):

Out-Null does not ignore errors. Out-Null redirects stdout (known as stream #1) to null. You can try doing a try catch (catch provides easy exceptions handling)

```
try {} 
catch {}
```

doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1

or redirect an error stream to void

```
Write-Error "ASD" 2>$null
```

doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$stop = $true
try {Get-AzureADDomain -Name $direct_routing_domain}
  catch  {
      $stop = $false
     }
```

OR

```
$stop = $true
$domain = Get-AzureADDomain | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $direct_routing_domain}

if ($null -eq $domain) {
    $stop = $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try{}..catch{}` on this, but remember to add `-ErrorAction Stop` (not 'Ignore') to the cmdlet to ensure also non-terminating exceptions are caught in the catch block:

```
# loop until we have found the newly added domain

$isProvisioned = $false
while (-not $isProvisioned) {
    try {
        $isProvisioned = [bool](Get-AzureADDomain -Name $direct_routing_domain -ErrorAction Stop)
    }
    catch { $isProvisioned = $false }
    if (!$isProvisioned) {
        Write-Host "Domain is not provisioned yet - retrying in 60 seconds..." -ForegroundColor Yellow 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
    }
}

Write-Host "Domain is provisioned " -ForegroundColor Green
```